# Change AllowEdits property based on Entry Date

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have number of split forms in an Access 2016 database which are regularly used by various employees for data entry. It is important that users are able to see old records but are not able to edit them.

However, I want to allow users to edit records that have been made that day in case they notice an error in a record they have just entered.

My current approach is to set the AllowEdits property on the form to yes, then to override it for entries made on the same day with the following code

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

If (Me![rec_date] < Now()) Then
Me.AllowEdits = False
Else: Me.AllowEdits = True

End If
End Sub
```

I think there is a problem with the If criteria though, as all this currently does is prevent editing of all records.

For background [rec_date] refers to the date on which the record was entered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things:

1. Use the "Current" event instead if you're working with record changes. Form Load only works when the form itself opens. If you change records it will do nothing for you.
2. Might as well move that Else statement down to the next line and indent correctly for readability.
3. Your conditional statement doesn't quite match what you told me. You're trying to match a specific day but you use a date time (now()) instead of date. You also use less than instead of equals. I would suggest using equals and the date function (note: doesn't use () and returns only the date portion of now() ).

Hopefully that helps! Here's my suggested code:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
    ' Only allow editing of records created today. 
    If (Me![rec_date] = Date) Then 
        Me.AllowEdits = True
    Else
        Me.AllowEdits = False
    End If
End Sub
```

An even shorter form as suggested by [Mat's Mug](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1188513/mats-mug)

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
    Me.AllowEdits = Me![rec_date] = Date ' Only allow editing of records created today. 
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not just do `Me.AllowEdits = Me![rec_date] = Date`? Note that the parentheses are redundant around the Boolean expression of the `If` statement.

Comment: Ha ha! The shorter it becomes.   No reason for me; just the way I like to keep things readable. I'll add your code as another short form!

Comment: Fantastic, thanks folks! Both bits of code worked. I'm pretty new to database management/ VBA so I really appreciate your help, I've learned a couple things here- I was near banging my head on the desk over this earlier today!

Thanks for the tip re: indentation too, that definitely does make the code easier to read.